# Проблема с внутренними страницами WP

Tags: php, wordpress

Вечер добрый, развернул сайт у себя на локалке. И при переходе на внутренние страницы выдает. И при авторизации с админки перенаправляет на боевой сайт. Подскажите пожалуйста в чем проблема?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/767561/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8-%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82-%D0%BD%D0%B0-wordpress/767562#767562